# DQS - Regex to detect invalid country names

Tags: sql-server, regex, data-quality-services

I'm creating a domain rule to avoid values in my country domain that won't correspond to country long name/two-letter code/Three-letter code/Numeric code and native title.

Could you please help me create a rule to capture native characters like hiraganas and Arabic letters?

This is how my domain values look like

[image]

I'm trying to capture values like

- البحرين(Bahrain)
- বাংলাদেশ (Bangladesh)
- កម្ពុជា (Cambodia)
- United Arab Emirates (الإمارات العربية المتحدة)

This is my progress so far

[image]

Also, I'm wondering what is the dialect used by DQS for regex.

Comment: The regex flavor being used is extremely likely the .NET one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use Unicode Categories on the regular expressions. Check how to do this here:

**https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html**

Answer (score 1):

You can make a single regex that matches multiple alternatives, the basic form is this:

```
^(A|B|C|D)$
```

where `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` represent your allowed patterns, e.g. `[0-9]{3}` and so on. Read: https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html

This way you only need a single (albeit longer) regex, which is probably easier to handle in the UI, and DQS only has to check the input value against a single expression, which is better for performance.

Comment: Thanks! Great suggestion. The only thing that I don't know how to do is to match patterns with international characters like البحرين

Comment: International characters are just characters. Write them into the regex.

Comment: That's the point of the question: How should I add special characters like Hiragana, Katakana, Han, and Latin?

Comment: Just write them into the regex as they are. "食" is not any less a character than "A" is.